# node.js express only return elements related to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

I want to only return the trades that belong to the currently logged in user. I store the user inside the header of each request. In each trade I have stored the creator.

My GET method looks like this:

```
exports.getTrades = (req, res, next) => {
  const tradeQuery = Trade.find();
  let fetchTrades;

  tradeQuery
    .then((trades) => {
      fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => t.creator._id === req.userData.userId); <---
      return;
    })
    .then((count) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Trades fetched successfully!",
        trades: fetchTrades,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Fetching trades failed!",
      });
    });
};
```

I tried console logging the two attributes i compare inside my filter manually, and there actually are trades where both are the same. **However fetchTrades remains empty.**

I really would appreciate some ideas.

Here are the two models:

user.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

trade.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const tradeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  pair: { type: String, required: true },
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  resultAmount: { type: Number, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: true },
  time: { type: Date, required: true },
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  leverage: { type: Number },
  entry: { type: Number },
  exit: { type: Number },
  lessonLearned: { type: String },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Trade", tradeSchema);
```

EDIT:
thats how the trade looks like:

```
{
  _id: 6245bf565043276fb456cb6a,
  pair: 'BTCUSD',
  type: 'long',
  resultAmount: 239,
  time: 2022-03-22T23:00:00.000Z,
  date: 2022-03-31T14:48:28.916Z,
  creator: 62409c68e17cae2d68a99b3b,
  leverage: 20,
  entry: 1.2321,
  exit: 1.2377,
  lessonLearned: 'I was good man',
  __v: 0
}
```

EDIT2:
Thanks to @vicki. I had to use "==" instead of "===" inside my filter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your usage of filter function. You are returning nothing instead of matched entries.

```
tradeQuery
.then((trades) => {
  fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => t.creator._id === req.userData.userId);
  return;
})
```

This is  your usage. Change it as

```
tradeQuery
.then((trades) => {
  fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => return t.creator._id === req.userData.userId);  
})
```

This should possibly fix your issue. Adding a js snippet

```js
let trades = [{
    "id": 1,
  "name": 'asd'
},
{
    "id": 2,
  "name": 'qwe'
},
{
    "id": 1,
  "name": 'efg'
}]

let fetchTrades

{
    fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => {
                       t.id === 1;
                       return
                  })
}

console.log('improper usage',fetchTrades)

{
    fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => {
                      return t.id === 1;
                  })
}

console.log('Proper usage',fetchTrades)
```

EDIT:
There may be issues when you compare ObjectIDs, using `===` will type check as well. So, it is advisable to use `t.creator._id.equals(req.userData.userId)` or `==`.
As @ApoorvaChikara pointed out, don't use the return statement inside filter function.

Comment: You don't need to return anything in the filter if you have one statement. this should work - fetchTrades = trades.filter((t) => t.creator._id === req.userData.userId);: it doesn't have any issues. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: The problem is with the creator data, it is not populating in the trades.

Comment: the approach with the return also gives an empty array. @ApoorvaChikara, i tried populating it with creator data, but it doesnt work. I receive the creator data fine without extra population.

Comment: Can you please add the mock data, it would be easy to answer?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, actually OP already used a return statement in the question. In his/her way of using filter(), fetchTrades will be empty; that's why i suggested returning on comparison.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i edited the original post

Comment: @manu.kanu, you are comparing two different types here with ```==```. Use ```.equals()``` or ```==``` when comparing objectID. Take a look at this http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals

Comment: @manu.kanu , I have updated the answer. If this solves the issue, do accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what helped me accomplish the filtering is the mongoose find() method. you can pass in a field which you want to match with an userid. in order to do this i implemented a repository file which exports all the db query functions. in my case i want to fetch all periods from a specific user.

my period.repo.ts looks like this:

```
// period.repo.ts
import Period from '../models/period.model';
 
class PeriodRepository {
  findAllFromUser(userId: String) {
    return Period.find({ userId: userId });
  }
   
}
    
export default new PeriodRepository();
```

then in my service file which contains my business logic for the backend i import and use the repo file like this:

```
// period.service.ts
import PeriodRepository from './period.repository';

getCycle(req, res) {
    let cycleLength = 1;
    let lastPeriod;
    PeriodRepository.findAllFromUser(req.params.userId)
      .then((periods) => {
        cycleLength = periodHelper.calcAverageCycleLength(periods, 0);
        if (lastPeriod?.endDate) {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'predictions fetched',
            cycleLength: cycleLength,
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'period is active',
            remainingDaysPeriod: 0,
            remainingDaysOvaluation: 0,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: 'fetching periods failed',
        });
      });
  }
```

this way i only query the documents which belong to the selected user.